# Is there a command for tidying trailing parentheses?

Tags: smartparens, paredit

When editing lisp code, I often end up with trailing parentheses scattered around (assuming `|` is point):

```
(defun example-function ()
  (let ((x (+ 1 1)))
    (when x
      (message x)|
      )
    ))
```

Are there any convenience commands for fixing this? Either in core Emacs, paredit/smartparens, or other packages?

I know I can press `)` and `paredit-close-round` will fix the next parenthesis, but I want to fix all of them in one command.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>i</kbd> (`lispy-tab`) from [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) does just that. Below is a screenshot of an ERT test visualization (using <kbd>xv</kbd> (`lispy-view-test`)).

[image: lispy-tab]

Comment: To clarify: point needs to be at the beginning of the defun for this to work, correct?

Comment: Yes, the operation always applies to the current sexp. Wouldn't want to re-indent unrelated code.